# Referral links on App Store / Google Play

Tags: android, ios, referrer

I have created a game and published it on App Store and Google Play, now I want to advertise it on a couple of websites. But how can I track where people came from? In the past, when we sold things on our own websites, we could use "document.referrer" and save it to database, but nowadays it's impossible to inject my own html/js code to App Store and Google Play pages where my game resides. Or is it?
How to do this on Google Play? On iTunes Store?

Answer (score 6):

First, other websites must add this tag to the URL `referrer=the.reference.site`

According to the Documentation:

> When your app is downloaded from Google Play Store, the Play Store app
>   broadcasts an `INSTALL_REFERRER` intent to your app during installation.
>   This intent contains the value of the referrer parameter of the link
>   used to reach your app's Google Play Store page, if one was present.

Then you should add a `BroadcastReceiver` to handle this reference.

Check this guide for [Campaign Measurement - Android SDK v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns#google-play-campaigns)